# CakePHP 2.2: Pre-populate AJAX "update" div?

Tags: ajax, forms, cakephp

This question is a little n00b-ish, but I haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution in the CakePHP docs or via google.

I'm trying to make a simple AJAX form that will update some information in a database, and also display that information on the page. The whole process seems straightforward enough, except I can't figure out how to pre-populate the update div.

In my view code, I have

```
<div id="interestingContent"></div>
<?
  echo $this->Form->create();
  // create form fields here
  echo $this->Js->submit('Save', array('update'=>'#interestingContent');
  echo $this->Form-end();
  echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
?>
```

This works great, and when the form is submitted, my controller correctly calls

```
$this->render('ajaxview','ajax')
```

and updates the `#interestingContent` div appropriately.

So, the question: What's the best way to pre-populate `#interestingContent` from the database? Of course I could just repeat the code from `ajaxview.ctp` inside `#interestingContent`, but it seems there must be a DRY way to do it.

My first thought was to make `ajaxview.ctp` an element, since I'm basically trying to embed one view inside another. That seems hackish to me, though, since my controller would then be rendering an element's view directly. I also considered the new view blocks in 2.1/2.2 but that doesn't seem right either.

I'm certain this sort of thing comes up all the time. Is there a generally accepted method of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. It may be hackish, but using an element wil do the  job.
First, create an element for representing your bd content.
In your form view, you use the element.
And you create another view that will contain only the element. This view will be the response to your ajax request. By using an element, you prevent code duplication.

Comment: I've sort of come to the same conclusion. I just did `$this->render('/Elements/Controllername/ajaxview');` on AJAX submission and it does have the desired result. Heck, maybe it's even the way you're "supposed" to do it, but I haven't seen any documentation of using elements like that.

Comment: CakePHP yes is open to ajax, but there is not a lot of documentation about it in the official doc I completely agree. But for your question I really think an element is the way, because ajax or not, you have two views that will contain the same thing and an element will prevent you from duplicating code.